# Encoding system for an image?

Tags: encoding, video-encoding

Like we have ASCII encoding system for characters. Then what is the encoding system used for other things such as an image, audio or video etc?

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is just one codec. A codec (short for encoder/decoder) is an agreement between party's how data should be record and transferred. That agreement is usually documented in the form of an RFC, or ISO document.

ASCII is documented in ISO/IEC 8859

There are many other text formats like UTF and ebcdic for example.

Just like text, there is not a single codec for audio, video and images. There are dozens, or even hundreds.

JPG/PNG are image codecs. Video is most commenly AVC, HEVC, VP9, AV1, YUV, But there are many more. Audio has mp3, AAC, Dolby Digital, Opus, PCM, and many many more.